# 0x80004005 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: asp.net, web-services, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am facing this problem while accessing web service from ASP.NET application.
But the problem occurs when it is hosted in a windows server.
When it is hosted in desktop it is working fine.
 I am calling web service with HttpWebRequest object.

Even it is working fine in server from HTML/Java Script application. Only problem occurs in ASP.NET application hosted in server. I get following error. IIS 8.0 is installed in server.

```
Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 153.2.228.76:443 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() at VSPTestApplication.UPS.CalculateRate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
System.IO.Stream GetRequestStream(System.Net.TransportContext ByRef)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  By hosted on your desktop, do you mean that the ASP.NET app as service client and the service are running on the same machine, your dev machine?  Refine your question a bit to make clearer the circumstance you are troubleshooting vs. the circumstance that works.

Comment: Thanks you very much for reply. It is just a ASP.NET application. I mean when it is hosted in IIS installed in my desktop it is working fine. But I host same application in IIS installed in Windows server then it is not working.

Comment: If the ASP.NET app as the service client and the service are on different machines when you get the error, then you need to troubleshoot connectivity from the client machine to the remote machine hosting the service with something simple - e.g. a web browser, `telnet` etc.

Comment: It is not a service client, it is just a ASP.NET application. The connectivity is fine when it is tested from a web browser with a HTML/Java script application. It is not working from ASP.NET application when the same is hosted in IIS in Windows server.

Answer (score 0):

Looking from your error message I notice that you are trying to hit a HTTPS url. This can be tricky when running in aspnet in IIS, because your code runs in a different user context. And the necessary certificates might not be installed in that context. For eg, if the target server has a certificate signed by a CA that is not trusted by the client's machine (asp.net/iis/windows) then the request wont succeed.

However, a certificate error would manifest clearly. it wouldnt show up as a failure to connect.

I suggest using system.net logging facility to create a logfile. That should help troubleshoot the problem. Also, you should run wireshark on the windows server and see where the server is trying to connect. It might be as simple as that the windows server does not have connectivity to the target. Or there might be a proxy in middle that is screwing up the network path.

To setup system.net logging, you can put the following config file in the same directory as the app that is running your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" />

<sources>
<source name="System.Net">

<listeners>
    <add name="System.Net"/>
</listeners>
</source>
<source name="System.Net.Sockets">
<listeners>
    <add name="System.Net"/>
</listeners>
</source>
<source name="System.Net.Cache">
<listeners>
    <add name="System.Net"/>
</listeners>
</source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
    <add
        name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="System.Net.trace.log"
    />
</sharedListeners>
<switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
    <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />               
    <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose" />
</switches>
```

for more details on logging:

[creating a tracelog with system.net](http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, and got solved just by troubleshooting the network.

in windows-> settings -> Network & Internet -> Network Troubleshooter